# IE setData drag and drop

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I am an amateur using WAMP to build a website. Not too expert with any of this.  I am just using standard W3school examples:

```
dragstart(ev){
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.currentTarget.id);}
```

*(have tried both 'text' & ev.target.id too)*

```
dropped(ev){ alert('card_id- ' + ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")); return true;)}
```

on this object:

```
<div class='my_draggable' id='1717' draggable='true' ondragstart='dragstart(event)'>
<a href='https://www.yahoo.com'>
  <div id='row_1'></div><div id='row_2'></div>
</a></div>
```

Every other browser the alert is:

```
'card_id- '1717'
```

IE alert is:
`'card_id- 'https://www.yahoo.com'`

what is different about IE method for setData?   I need IE to behave like the other browsers.

Deepek

Here is your code, modified to replicate what I am doing.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .droptarget {
      float: left; 
      width: 100px; 
      height: 35px;
      margin: 15px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    }

    a {
      color: inherit;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Drag the p element back and forth between the two rectangles:</p>

    <div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div>
      <div ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="1717">
         <a href='https://www.yahoo.com'>
         <div id='row_1'>drag</div>
         <div id='row_2'>me</div>
         <div id='row_3'>please</div>
         </a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div>

    <p style="clear:both;">
    <strong>Note:</strong> drag events are not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions
                 or Safari 5.1 and earlier versions.</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function dragStart(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Started to drag the p element";
    }

    function allowDrop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    function drop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

  alert('card_id- ' + event.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refer this modified example code. It is giving the similar result in IE and other browsers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.droptarget {
  float: left; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 35px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the p element back and forth between the two rectangles:</p>

<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <p ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="1717">Drag me!
  <a href='https://www.yahoo.com'>
  <div id='row_1'></div><div id='row_2'></div>
</a></div>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<p style="clear:both;"><strong>Note:</strong> drag events are not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions or Safari 5.1 and earlier versions.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function dragStart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Started to drag the p element";
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element was dropped";
  alert('card_id- ' + event.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

Reference:

(1) [DataTransfer.getData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData)

(2) [DataTransfer.setData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData)

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen,  Thanks for your responses.   I didn't realize this until I after I had posted my problem.....   On my computer,  this problem is not occurring.      The problem is only occurring on my site where it is hosted,  out on Hostmonster.    So...this is fine on my desktop for all browsers, this works fine on Hostmonster, except for Microsoft browsers.   I have a support ticket open with them!

Comment: I'm at a standstill now.   Hostmonster is telling me the problem is a scripting problem and is in my lap.   But these scripts run fine on my desktop, the difference is when they are run on hostmonster.     Is it possible that they are manipulating the DOM object in some way that could cause this problem?

Comment: Deepak, thanks for your example.   It helped me at least make some progress....  I changed the <p> that I was dragging to to a <div> and it still worked as expected.   This made me realize that the 'Drag me!' was actually the InnerHTML of the <div>.    When I move 'Drag me!' into one id="Row1" or "Row2" divs,  then the alert can no longer identify the card_iD.     I was seeing the <div id='1717'  draggable='true'>  as a container for the other elements, but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: Can you try to find any difference in configuration or in settings between your machine and problematic machine? It can give some idea about the issue. also let us know, If there is any way to produce the issue on our side. We will try to produce it and try to find the cause for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
dragstart(ev){
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
dropped(ev){ 
 alert('card_id- ' + ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
 return true;
}
```